# Error Code: Error in function {x}: attempt to bind a variable to R_UnboundValue

Tags: r, unbound

I have the below dataset

```
Sales = data.frame(Category = c(1,2,3,3,2,3,3,4), Sale_period= c(Mar-20,Apr-20,Mar-20,May-20,Feb-20,Mar-20,Mar-20,Jan-20), SalesVol = c(847,143,554,30,44,140,445,847))
```

I am trying to find out the sales by categories, according to the latest Sales period in each category.

```
Latest = Sales %>%
     group_by(Category) %>%
     filter(Sale_period == max(Sale_period) %>%
     mutate(LatestSales = SalesVol)
```

I get the following error: `Error in filter_impl(data., quo):
attempt to bind a variable to R_UnboundValue`. Not sure if this is a dplyr problem as I have seen users with similar problems, such as this.
[Problems with dplyr summarise function of the latest R version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340269/problems-with-dplyr-summarise-function-of-the-latest-r-version/62341234#62341234)

Appreciate any advice please, cant seem to find much of this error online. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting `Error: object 'Mar' not found` when I try to evaluate `Mar-20` .

Comment: `Sale_period` should probably be a valid "Date".

Comment: Apologies those are made up data. But i dont think the problem is with the column type because when i change it to "filter(X = max(X)) using another numeric column X, i stil get the same error

Comment: Maybe if you fixed the syntax errors (missing closing parens).

Comment: Sorry Edward what is that you mean please?